# PHP download entire folder (recursive) via FTP

Tags: php, ftp, download, backup, host

I currently have a very large site approximately 5gb in size with 60,000 files. The current host isn't doing much in the way of helping me transfer the site to the new host and what I was thinking was to make a simply script on my new host to FTP into the old host and download the entire public_html folder (recursively) to the new server. Is this possible and if so, does anyone have any links they could share to aid in this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you get an FTP client (Filezilla, etc.) and just transfer it to your disk, then to the new FTP? My question is why you need a PHP script to do this.

Comment: Or if you have ssh access, use `scp` instead.

Comment: The reason is as stated. The site is approximately 5GB in size with over 60,000 files. To download the entire site manually as it is, would take a number of hours, and to upload the site to the new server would take even longer. I'm looking for a direct route from old server -> new server without involving me as middle man. That should give the fastest solution possible.

Comment: If you have shell access on the new host, simply use `wget`. It can do a recursive FTP w/o trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are probably better mechanisms to do what you want to do.

First, can you use `sftp` or `scp` from one host to the other?

```
scp -R username@oldhost:path/to/directory/ /path/to/destination/directory
```

or

```
sftp username@oldhost  # then use 'get -r' to download recursively
```

or

```
rsync -avz -P username@oldhost:/path/to/directory/ /path/to/destination/directory/
```

The `-P` makes it easy to restart a stalled/dead download.

If good tools won't work, then see if `wget` is installed:

```
wget --mirror --continue --ftp-user=username ftp://oldhost/path/to/directory/
```

The `--continue` makes it easier to restart a stalled/dead download.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no server access to either of the servers. The old host is refusing to assist in the transfer and the new host wants to charge me through the roof to run the simple SSH commands you have mentioned above. So now, I'm left searching for a solution using the limited resources I have.

Comment: @Brian, well perhaps you could just [`system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) that `wget` command from a PHP script, but it sounds like reason enough to find a _new_ new provider. :)

Comment: I've managed to successfully execute some wget commands via system(). As s3v3n has mentioned below, my initial thoughts were to zip up the data, and I've managed to do this too on the old host again using system(). Thanks to you both, the new server is now downloading the archive as we speak.

Comment: sorry, no satisfying solution for me, as I need a cross platform nearly php-only solution

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but if my "new" host was being that difficult in trying to get my data moved to THEIR platform, I'd probably re-think using them as my hosting provider.

Answer (score 2):

If there are a lot of files, I strongly recomend you to make a .tar.gz archive.
I don't know what restrictions to php do you have but you can try this one in php:

```
$archive = "backup.tar.gz";
$directory = "./www";
exec( "tar -czf $archive $directory");
```

Then you can simply download 1 single gziped archive via http / ftp or using any other method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it in pure PHP !

I've just released 2 new libraries to do such things in [FTP](https://github.com/hugsbrugs/php-ftp) / [SFTP](https://github.com/hugsbrugs/php-sftp)

Recursively copy files and folders on remote SFTP server (If local_path ends with a slash upload folder content otherwise upload folder itself)

```
Ftp::upload_dir($server, $user, $password, $local_path, $remote_path, $port = 22);
```

Download a directory from remote FTP server (If remote_dir ends with a slash download folder content otherwise download folder itself)

```
Ftp::download_dir($server, $user, $password, $remote_dir, $local_dir,
```

$port = 22);

If you want to look at the code, you will see recursive functions that do the magic ;)